# К какому разряду относится наречие "опять"?

Tags: морфология, наречия

Подскажите, пожалуйста,  "опять" - это наречие времени? Или его лучше рассматривать как наречие образа действия?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ОПЯТЬ. I. нареч. Ещё раз, снова. О. идёт снег. Поезд о. опоздал. Это об-ство времени и отвечает на вопрос (когда?). Оно не может быть об-ством образа действия. См. значение.